# How can I use build_number variable from jenkins as a tag for a reactjs docker image?

Tags: reactjs, docker, jenkins, package.json

I'm trying to create a tag for each docker image generated with a jenkins job, for this I'm looking of how can I call an environment variable from jenkins such as build_number on my package.json

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your docker image from Jenkins job using following command.

`docker build -f Dockerfile -t react-image:${env.BUILD_NUMBER} .`

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether you want a version number defined inside package.json or the jenkins build number as the previous answer gave you.

In case you want a version number defined inside your package.json you could fetch it with `grep` inside a jenkins shell command and then use docker build as the above answer suggested.

If the version/build number is simply a shell environment variable, then you could use the environment variable injection plugin to export it to Jenkins.